# Python using Tk button

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm using python GUI (TK). I have a button that runs a long procedure - but I want it to be disabled immediately after clicking it.
It looks like this:

```
button = tk.Button(self, text="blabla", command= lambda: self.foo(param, button)
def foo(self, button):
      button.configure (state = "disabled")
      #now call the function that takes time
      goo()
def goo():
   doLongAction()
```

The problem is the button is disabled only after goo() returns and then foo returns.
Is there a way to disable it right away?
Thanks

Comment: You should fix your indentation so it's easier to see what's going on.

Comment: I edited it so it would be easier to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the button widget after you disable it by calling the [`update_idletasks`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.update_idletasks-method) method:

```
button = tk.Button(self, text="blabla", command= lambda: self.foo(param, button)
def foo(self, button):
      button.configure (state = "disabled")
      ##########################
      button.update_idletasks()
      ##########################
      #now call the function that takes time
      goo()
def goo():
   doLongAction()
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure I understand how to use it... How should I modify my code above? Should I leave the command as foo or change it?

Comment: @user2950329 - You would call the `update_idletasks` method just after the line when you disable the button.  See my edit.